# Trying to restore InnoDB tables

Tags: mysql, innodb, restore, ubuntu

I've reinstalled MySQL but when I copy the data dir from the old instance:

```
maicol07@maicol07$ sudo mysqld --user=root
2020-07-14T13:07:34.031447Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) starting as process 90378
2020-07-14T13:07:34.446932Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2020-07-14T13:07:37.429706Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012209] [InnoDB] Multiple files found for the same tablespace ID:
2020-07-14T13:07:37.430405Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012202] [InnoDB] Tablespace ID: 3 = ['mysql/gtid_slave_pos.ibd', 'mysql/servers.ibd']

2020-07-14T13:07:37.431128Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Failed, retry may succeed.
2020-07-14T13:07:37.431713Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
mysqld: Error on delete of 'mysql_dd_upgrade_info' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)
2020-07-14T13:07:37.433160Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2020-07-14T13:07:37.434617Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-07-14T13:07:37.438495Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1)  (Ubuntu).
```

I think MySQL started upgrading from 5.7 to 8, but I'm not sure...
Can you help me?
Thanks